# Read cpu affinity in java

Tags: java, affinity

with the "affinity" param in windows or the "taskset" command in linux its possible to restrict a (java) application to a defined set of cpus/cores. Is it possible to get that affinity information (in example for licencing purposes) in the started java application?

Thank you and best regards

Ben

Comment: Not without native code of some kind.  You've already cited a difference between windows and java.  That's not "write once, run anywhere" behavior.

Comment: If it is like @duffymo claims, one way could be to start the Java application by a native wrapper that does those checks and somehow forwards it to the Java code.